# Filter customer will come again with SQL based on week

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets saying my data is

```
CREATE TABLE memberdata
(
    CustomerID CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY not null,
    CustomerName VARCHAR(255),
    CustomerGender VARCHAR(20),
)
SELECT * FROM memberdata
insert into memberdata(CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerGender)
values('C001','Alan','Male'),('C002','Lana','Female'),('C003','Aan','Male'),
('C004','Nala','Female');
```

And for the content:

```
CREATE TABLE TrTransaktion(
TransID CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
CustomerID CHAR (7) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES memberdata (CustomerID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
Sales INT,
TransDate date,
)
SELECT * FROM TrTransaktion
insert into TrTransaktion(TransID,CustomerID,Sales,TransDate)
values('TR001','C001',34,'2022-09-03'),('TR002','C002',23,'2022-09-02'),('TR003','C003',132,'2022-09-03'),
('TR004','C004',95,'2022-09-02'),('TR005','C002',68,'2022-09-08'),('TR006','C001',54,'2022-09-05'),
('TR007','C002',34,'2022-09-11'),('TR008','C002',98,'2022-09-23'),('TR009','C004',34,'2022-09-19'),
('TR010','C001',30,'2022-09-18'),('TR011','C003',34,'2022-09-26');
```

Last i Add weeks:

```
ALTER TABLE TrTransaktion ADD Weeks int;
UPDATE TrTransaktion SET Weeks = datepart(week, TransDate);
```

I would to find  who come by based (week 36).if the customers come to week 37 they will not appear in other week (38, 39, 40)

hope the result will show about:
week 37 = CS002 CS001, week 38 = -, week 39 = CS004, week 40 = CS003

(can be modified but that's the point)

Comment: SQL Server <>  MySQL; what RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: for the data using mysql